# Bitbucket pipeline: Deploy fresh commit on Tomcat in an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, tomcat, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I have a bitbucket repository for my server side code which is deployed in tomcat. My development testing environment is an AWS EC2 linux instance. With every single change needed to be tested in the environment requires following steps:

- Pull the fresh commit with command `$ git pull`
- Build code using maven `$ mvn clean install`
- Stop existing instance of tomcat, which I do manually using `Ctrl+C`
- Restart tomcat using maven `$ mvn tomcat7:run`

I want to automate the process using bitbucket pipeline, but I have no idea how to implement it. I have very basic knowledge about **bitbcket-pipeline.yml** as I used it for deploying my code to S3. Please help.